# how get data from 3 tables? function

Tags: php, mysql, function, codeigniter, module

i have error how fix that? "Column 'title' in where clause is ambiguous":

```
    get_results_from($search_term='default')
    $targets=array('a_table','b_table','c_table');
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($targets);
    $this->db->like('title',$search_term);
    $this->db->or_like('body', $search_term);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with

```
<?php
get_results_from($search_term='default');
$sql =  "SELECT * from a_table where `title` LIKE '%".$search_term."%' OR `body` LIKE '%".$search_term."%'
        UNION
        SELECT * from b_table where `title` LIKE '%".$search_term."%' OR `body` LIKE '%".$search_term."%' 
        UNION
        SELECT * from c_table where `title` LIKE '%".$search_term."%' OR `body` LIKE '%".$search_term."%' ";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
return $query->result_array();
?>
```

Comment: All three tables must have same structure, ie, they must have equal number of fields. Is it?

Comment: all tables have title, body but others fields is different.

Comment: what about number of fields?

Comment: Ok Then Try With   `%".$searchterm."%` instead of `$searchterm`.

Comment: then i have errors: Undefined variable: searchterm

Filename: models/Search_model.php

Comment: all tables have 21fields with differents fields like "category_a" in other table "category_b"

Comment: possibly multiple tables contain column name 'title'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function get_results_from($search_term='default')
{
    $targets=array('a_table','b_table','c_table');
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($targets);
    $this->db->group_start();
       $this->db->like('a_table.title',$search_term);
       $this->db->or_like('b_table.title',$search_term);
       $this->db->or_like('c_table.title',$search_term);
       $this->db->or_like('body', $search_term);
    $this->db->group_end();
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: then showing results from last table in array and repeats 3 times.. http://prntscr.com/fdwuha

Comment: Try the updated code. Put every search_term inside the group() as above.